# How to represent a startup screen in Storyboards

Tags: ios, swift

Right now I have a `MainViewController` which is embedded in a `UINavigationController` so the navigation controller is set as initial view controller.

What I want is first time the app starts and only then to show a `StartupViewController`. But I am not sure how to represent this in my storyboard.

Should this be set as initial view controller if the app starts the first time, if not the navigation controller should be set.

What I tried is to show `StartupViewController` in `MainViewController::viewDidLoad()`, but its not working how I wanted too.

Anyone know what is the right approach to do this ?

Comment: Why dont you used LaunchScreen.Storyboard for startup screen

Comment: Can you post some code from your appDelegate? One more thing to ask that as per your question you want a custom loading screen of yours right..??

Comment: Yes, I want a screen that says if you want to load data from iCloud, or just start Fresh. And this should be shown only once when u start the app for the first time

Comment: @VivekGajbe: maybe startup is not the correct word, I need an Intro screen to show only once when the app is started the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello this code may be helpfull for you :

```
// MARK: - Application Supporting Funcations -
func loadFirstViewController(viewController: String)
{
    // for loading first view Controller
    let storyBoard = appDelegate.AppStoryBoard()
    /////////////////////////Add Navigation Controller and set Root View Controller///////////////////////////////////////
    let object = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(viewController) // for prelogin navigation
    self.navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: object)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
    self.loadNavigationControllerToWindow()
}

func loadNavigationControllerToWindow()
{
    if self.window == nil
    {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    }
    // for loading root view
    self.window!.rootViewController = self.navigationController!
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

call this function in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
    if((NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("isFirstTime") != nil))
        {
            self.loadFirstViewController("LoginVC") // for loading first view controller
        }
        else
        {
            self.loadFirstViewController("WelcomeVC") // for loading first view controller
        }
```

put this after you go in second controler viewDidLoad

```
  if((NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("isFirstTime") == nil))
    {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue("1", forKey: "isFirstTime")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is how I acheived in my app.** 
Add this in appdelegate applicationdidfinishlaunching.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (![defaults boolForKey:@"FirstTime"])
{ 
    //NSLog(@"Enter First Time ");
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    StartupViewController * firstViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StartupViewController"];//AskAndAnswerViewId  RegisterViewId TagViewId HelpViewId
    self.navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
else    
{  
    //NSLog(@"not First Time");
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    HelpViewController *mainviewcontroller = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AskAndAnswerViewId"];
    self.navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mainviewcontroller];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
```

**Once you reached in Mainviewcontroller change the userdefault value for FirstTime to "NO".**

Answer (score 1):

I understand your Question ,

In `AppDelegate` try to set rootViewController ,

I have store data in the `NSUserDefault` if user came first time
And try to set rootViewController once he visit first time.

In below Example I have navigate user to Login screen/Home screen

```
let str = userDefaults.objectForKey("firstTime")  
{}else{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't forget to give identifier to your view controller `StartupViewController`

-> user interaction enable in StartupViewController

```
  if  (UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "keepUsername") != nil) {


        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Revealview")
        self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginview") as! loginview
        self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
     }
```

Comment: I know how to create it, I don't know how to represent the VC only once, when the app is started the first time.

Comment: mean you wanna say only first time StartupViewController display?